# Render HTML Page

Tags: html

This is my html page.

```
<body>
<div id="form1">
    <root xmlns:NS='www.yembi.com'>
    <NS:ENTRY Action='Users'>
    <div class="colm1">
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="FirstName"></NS:DISPLAY>             
    </div>
    <div class="colm2">
        <NS:Text datafield='FirstName'/>
    </div>
    <div class="colm1">
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="MiddleName"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </div>
    <div class="colm2">
        <NS:Text datafield='MiddleName'/>
    </div>
    <div class="colm1">
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="LastName"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </div>
    <div class="colm2">
        <NS:Text datafield='LastName'/>
    </div>
    <div class="colm1">
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="Phone"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </div>
    <div class="colm2">
       <NS:Text datafield='Phone'/>
    </div>
    <div class="colm3">
        <NS:BUTTON ></NS:BUTTON>
    </div>
    </NS:ENTRY>
    </root>
</div>
```

I wanna get this html into a temp variable. so tried like below

```
var Text = $("#form1").html();
```

I am getting full html content, But with small exceptions.
It not displaying the double quotes in div attributes.

I am getting the below output:

```
<ROOT xmlns:NS='www.yembi.com'>
    <NS:ENTRY Action='Users'>
    <DIV class=colm1>
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="FirstName"></NS:DISPLAY>             
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm2>  // Here it automatically removes the double quotes. how to retain this double quotes ?
        <NS:Text datafield='FirstName'/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm1>
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="MiddleName"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm2>
        <NS:Text datafield='MiddleName'/>
    </div>
    <DIV class=colm1>
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="LastName"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm2>
        <NS:Text datafield='LastName'/>
    </DIV>
    <DIVclass=colm1>
        <NS:DISPLAY datafield="Phone"></NS:DISPLAY>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm2>
       <NS:Text datafield='Phone'/>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class=colm3>
        <NS:BUTTON ></NS:BUTTON>
    </DIV>
    </NS:ENTRY>
    </ROOT>
```

As mentioned above it automatically remove the double quotes in DIV. How to retain this double quotes??

Comment: It is still valid HTML without the quotes, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using jQuery or an equivalent:

See here from the documentation:
    "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters."

http://api.jquery.com/html/

So this is really browser dependent. You could use a javascript regex to make sure the quotes are where you need them to be:
[Regex to put quotes for html attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622483/regex-to-put-quotes-for-html-attributes)

Comment: Thanks mihaisimi... Regex to put quotes for html attributes - this link working fine.. :)